# how to find out the start time of last sleep

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake

Is there a command to find the date and time at which a Macintosh computer last entered the sleep mode?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the `pmset` command to obtain this information. The following command obtains a log of the sleep/wake entries then restricts this to the last entry in the list which should be the most recent sleep:

`pmset -g log | grep sleep | tail -n 1`

You can obviously play around with anything after `pmset -g log` to give you what you need.

Comment: hey thanks that worked! just changed the `grep` command to `grep -2 sleep` to get the line with the date and time.

Comment: Oh yes, now that's what I'm talking about. Precise sleep info and not some log file grepping hoping to catch a hint of sleep. :-)

Comment: `grep sleep` might also match other lines. Something like `pmset -g log | grep -E '^.{24} sleep  '` should probably be used in scripts.

Comment: @Lri Agreed. I did lash the original command up in about 5 seconds and is also why I added the last sentence ;-) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Not working for me. It prints out incorrect date

Comment: This worked for me on 10.11.5: `pmset -g log | grep "Display is turned off" | tail -1`

Answer (score 140):

Actually, something like

```
pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "
```

is what really gives me a clean timeline of sleep/wake events on 10.8.2. powerd does not log anything about it, at least on my system (10.8.2, MacBook Pro Retina 15).

```
02/03/13 19:48:37 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:99%)                              26 secs   
02/03/13 19:49:03 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:99%)                              27 secs   
02/03/13 19:49:30 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:99%)                              26 secs   
02/03/13 19:49:56 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:99%)                              26 secs   
02/03/13 19:50:22 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:99%)                              26 secs   
02/03/13 19:50:48 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:99%)                              26 secs   
02/03/13 19:51:14 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:100%)                             1802 secs 
02/03/13 20:39:17 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:100%)                           244 secs  
02/03/13 20:43:21 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:100%)                             51 secs   
02/03/13 21:07:17 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:100%)                           242 secs  
02/03/13 21:11:19 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:100%)                             1103 secs 
02/03/13 21:29:42 GMT-03 Wake       Wake due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open: Using AC (Charge:100%)                     
03/03/13 00:00:26 GMT-03 Sleep      Idle Sleep Sleep: Using BATT (Charge:85%)                                   96 secs   
03/03/13 00:02:02 GMT-03 Sleep      Maintenance Sleep Sleep: Using AC (Charge:85%)                              38 secs   
03/03/13 00:02:40 GMT-03 Wake       Wake due to EHC1/HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:85%)                        4338 secs 
03/03/13 01:14:58 GMT-03 Sleep      Clamshell Sleep to DarkWake: Using AC (Charge:100%)                         48382 secs
03/03/13 14:41:20 GMT-03 Wake       DarkWake to FullWake due to HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:100%)            728 secs  
03/03/13 14:53:28 GMT-03 Sleep      Clamshell Sleep to DarkWake: Using AC (Charge:100%)                         415 secs  
03/03/13 15:00:23 GMT-03 Wake       DarkWake to FullWake due to HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:100%)            718 secs  
03/03/13 15:12:21 GMT-03 Sleep      Clamshell Sleep to DarkWake: Using AC (Charge:100%)                         156 secs  
03/03/13 15:14:57 GMT-03 Wake       DarkWake to FullWake due to HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:100%)            834 secs  
03/03/13 15:28:51 GMT-03 Sleep      Clamshell Sleep to DarkWake: Using AC (Charge:100%)                         378 secs 
03/03/13 15:35:09 GMT-03 Wake       DarkWake to FullWake due to HID Activity: Using AC (Charge:100%)
```

Comment: This is great, ta!!

Comment: Use `pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  " -e " DarkWake  "` for all wakes including `DarkWake`'s

Comment: @Tieme, pldg, How do I get more records? It only shows **2 weeks**.

Comment: Best answer, accepted didn't work for me. 2016 Macbook.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Works on monterey

Comment: Works on Sonoma 14.3.1, great answer, thanks

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `pmset -g log | grep LidOpen` if you want to know when the lid of your MacBook was opened.

Comment: What about for lid closed?

Comment: MacBooks enter sleep mode 15 seconds after the lid is closed. You can see when your machine entered sleep mode due to closing the lid with the command `pmset -g log | grep 'Clamshell Sleep'`. Subtract 15 seconds to get the exact time the lid was closed.

Comment: On MacOs High Sierra 10.13

pmset -g log | grep -e "Display is turned on"

Answer (score 5):

There may be a more efficient way to get the exact last time, but on lion you can search for `powerd` entries in `/private/var/log/system.log`

If you like terminal, something like `grep powerd /private/var/log/system.log` works well. The Console app also has a nice search ability to filter these logs.

If there was no sleep event since the last time the the log file rolled over, you can use Console or `bzgrep` instead of `grep` to search the `system.log.*.bz2 files`.

Comment: I don't get any results for `powerd` in any of the system logs, could I be missing some setting for logging `powerd` activities?

Comment: If you sleep and wake and that doesn't show, then you might just look at the file at the exact time you slept the mac to see the messages your mac is making.

Comment: @bmike, How to see the time of the last screen password-unlock? (not sleep/unsleep)