# How can I see the sleep time(s) of my mac for a specific date?

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake

Is it possible to see when I put my mac to sleep on a specific date?

Comment: I ended up using pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "

Comment: Hi @Vincent, if you solved your issue, you may post it as an answer and accept it; it may help others and won't appear as unanswered for the rest of the community. Thanks!

Comment: added bounty because I need to go back further than 2 weeks..

Comment: I think there's no way to recover the old logs from before 2 weeks if you didn't installed an app like Sleep Monitor way before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer in this so question:[how to find out the start time of last sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52064/how-to-find-out-the-start-time-of-last-sleep)

Luckily the date I had in mind wasn't too long ago so I was able to use

```
pmset -g log|grep -e " Sleep  " -e " Wake  "
```

Comment: Nice, it looks like it goes back as far as 2 weeks with the history log. (+) from me. Just out of interest, why do you need to know that?

Comment: @Buscar웃  forgot to log my work when doing a job for a client

Answer (score 4):

For 10.9 and earlier, you could use the application [Sleep Monitor](http://dssw.co.uk/sleepmonitor/index.html).

Sleep Monitor is an application I wrote that produces logs and graphs of power on/off, sleep, wake, and battery levels:

[image: DssW Sleep Monitor]