# Network client is released unexpectedly and mac goes to sleep

Tags: network, imac, ssh

My jenkins builds crash because of broken ssh pipes into my iMac.
The ssh connection is dropped unexpectedly and the iMac instantly enters sleep state. I cant figure out why. Here's the `pmset -g log`output:

```
2018-06-22 14:49:16 +0200 Assertions  PID 48(powerd) Released NetworkClientActive "com.apple.powermanagement.ttyassertion" 00:09:19  id:0x11000013f7 [System: PrevIdle]
2018-06-22 14:49:16 +0200 Sleep       Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep': Using AC                     77 secs
```

I cant figure out why `NetworkClientActive` gets released nor do I find any information about this. Where do I find logs why the sleep happens?

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I find logs why the sleep happens?

[how to find out the start time of last sleep](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52064/how-to-find-out-the-start-time-of-last-sleep)

> You can use the pmset command to obtain this information. The
>   following command obtains a log of the sleep/wake entries then
>   restricts this to the last entry in the list which should be the most
>   recent sleep:
>
> `pmset -g log | grep sleep | tail -n 1`
>
> You can obviously play around with anything after pmset -g log to give
>   you what you need.

Comment: The `pmset -g log` output was posted, I know about these logs. What I am searching for is why `NetworkClientReleased`was happening. Thank you anyway.